# How to scroll a vertical scrollbar (not the whole page)?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, scrollbar

I'm currently trying to scroll a vertical scroll-bar without scrolling the whole page, I want it to implement javascript.

here is the code I'm using with:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp");
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("leftmenuinnerinner"))).MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("leftmenuinner"))).Build().Perform();
for (int i =0;i <= 1000; i++)
{
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,10)");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

with this code the whole page starts scrolling and not the scroll bar. so any ideas on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

The below one worked for me.The element can be a element until which you want to scroll.
`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("yourelement"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);`

or you can try the below one.

```
findElement(By.xpath("yourelement").sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
```